# Make td have editable background color in Mailchimp's editor

Tags: editor, edit, background-color, mailchimp

I'm setting up a custom template for a client where they want to be able to change the background color of some of the elements using the editor. I added an mc:edit property but it doesn't seem to have any effect - the property can't be changed. What else do I need to specify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the editable [css](/questions/tagged/css) tags in a style declaration block. You can put any [html](/questions/tagged/html) tag in there that you want your client to be able to edit.

Example:

(copy and save in your template editor, and open in your campaign editor).

```
<html>
    <head>

    <style type="text/css">

    /*
    @tab Body
    @section body style
    @tip Set the background color for your email's body area.
    */
    #table{
        /*@editable*/background-color:#888888;
    }

    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table id="table">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div mc:edit="content">
                        Lorem ipsum
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Make sure that you give any editable part a unique mc:edit ID.

Source: http://templates.mailchimp.com/getting-started/template-language/

Comment: Ah, yes I've seen this but as I understand it doesn't let the client choose any color, only the ones that you declare in the code. I was looking for some form of color wheel for the client to pick with in the editor.

Comment: @StaffanEstberg: when I save this html in a template I can create a new campaign, select this template, and then click on the specific tab to edit the background color with a color picker. 

Example screenshot: http://imgur.com/0aWT9DX

I presume this is what you are looking for?

Comment: Ah yes that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks McVenco!